# How can I check which file is modified in specific directory?

Tags: files-and-directories

I want to find which files are recently modified in a specific directory. For this purpose, I wrote a function named `Test`.

The function's argument is `DirectoryPath`, and it returns file names whose file dates have been modified. In this example the functions runs once every five seconds.

For this purpose I wrote the following code, but it shows all the file names that are in the directory. That means it doesn't check the `ModificationDate` with `lastModified`.

```
Test[directoryPath_] := Module[{taskId,
   fileNames = FileNames["*", SystemDialogInput["Directory"]],
   lastModified,
   result},
  (
   lastModified = Table[{}, {Length[fileNames]}];
   result = Table[{}, {Length[fileNames]}];
   taskId = 
    CreateScheduledTask[
     Table[(With[{
        i = i, 
        modificationDate = 
          Table[FileDate[Part[fileNames, j], "Modification"],
            {j, 1, Length[fileNames]}]
         },
       (If[(Part[lastModified, i] === Part[modificationDate, i]),
         (Part[result, i] =  ""), 
         (Part[lastModified, i] = Part[modificationDate, i];
          Part[result, i] = Part[fileNames, i])])]),
      {i, 1, Length[fileNames]}],
     {OptionValue[ScanRate], \[Infinity]}];
   StartScheduledTask[taskId];
   {taskId, Dynamic[result]}
   )]

Test[SystemDialogInput["Directory"]]
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Could you be more specific than "it doesn't work"?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I edited my question,can you check it once.

Comment: @subbu: I think your code has at leat 2 problems and seems to be more complicated than what would be necessary to demonstrate your problem. Have you any indication that this only fails when run as a `ScheduledTask`? If not, then you'd better simplify the code to run without it. Here are some potential problems that you want to investigate: a) using `fileNames` in the RHS of the local variable definitions of `Module` most probably doesn't do what you expect. b) comparing the result of `FileDate` doesn't look right, I'd rather suggest to convert it to an `AbsoluteTime` and check with e.g. `>`.

Comment: @AlbertRetey  again,I updated my question with updated code..could you check it once..

Comment: @subbu You should not update the version of the code in your question each time we find an error in  it. In the end the whole question doesn't make sense anymore. Furthermore, I spent considerable time in improving the horrible layout of the original code and your replacement nullifies that all.

Comment: @subbu: I actually didn't mean that you should incorporate my suggestions into the code in the questions but use them to solve your problem -- if that would be the case you could very well write an answer to your own question showing the working code. What I mainly hoped for was a simplified version which concentrates on what exactly doesn't work -- which would most probably make you find a solution yourself...

Comment: This seems to be more a StackExchange-etiquette problem. @subbu I'd say reverse your updates and the downvotes may go...The question is still an important one and the downvote does not reflect this really.

Comment: @Stefan I don't know,how to reverse my updates.

Comment: @subbu either seize a time-machine or just post your original question with your original code ;) If this does not work for you...well then...dunno

Comment: @Stefan the above code was also not working for me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a minimally changed version of your program that works:

```
Test[directoryPath_] :=
 Module[
  {
   fileNames = FileNames["*", directoryPath],
   lastModified,
   taskId,
   booleanValue = {}
   },
  lastModified = Table[{}, {Length[fileNames]}];
  taskId =
   CreateScheduledTask[
    booleanValue =
     Table[
      With[{j = j, 
        modificationDate = FileDate[fileNames[[j]], "Modification"]},
       If[(lastModified[[j]] === modificationDate),
        "",
        lastModified[[j]] = modificationDate;
        fileNames[[j]]
        ]
       ],
      {j, 1, Length[fileNames]}
      ],
    {5, \[Infinity]}
    ];
  StartScheduledTask[taskId];
  (*Output*)
  Dynamic[booleanValue]
  ]
```

I moved the initialization of `lastModified` outside the local variable definition section, because you can't define local variable in terms of other local variables. I changed a `==` into a `=` and a `==` into a `===`.

I also removed all non-functional `(  )` pairs in your code.